# Opportunity Product Validation Rule Overinclusive

Tags: opportunity, validation-rule, opportunity-lineitem

We use Relative Pricing code in our Org, which causes a recalculation of Opp. Prod Unit Sales Price if one of several fields are edited. For this example, let's say those fields are the Total Deal Price (currency) and the Commercial Launch Date (date field which calculates beginning of Term).

My goal from this Validation is to prohibit Opp Prod changes after Manager Approval (Quote Status field below) or Stages 5+. The problem here is that I want to allow the recalculation to occur, but only if Product Quantity and Unit Sales Price (rounded) remain the same. Unfortunately, as written, any recalculation is prohibited as it modifies the Opp Prod record. I'd appreciate any help provided.

`OR( 
ISPICKVAL (Opportunity.Quote_Status__c, "Approved"), 
ISPICKVAL (Opportunity.StageName, "5 - Negotiate"), 
ISPICKVAL (Opportunity.StageName, "6 - Contract"), 
ISPICKVAL (Opportunity.StageName, "7 - Closing"), 
ISPICKVAL (Opportunity.StageName, "Closed Won"), 
ISPICKVAL (Opportunity.StageName, "Closed Lost")) && Opportunity.RecordTypeId <> "012j0000000piiH"`

Comment: Not to question what you're doing, but there are business reasons NOT to do this. Have you been specifically directed by your management to make this change?

Comment: Did you look at the PRIORVALUE() function?

Comment: Good day @crmprogdev, not only have we discussed it, but we allow for reversion of Stages, and Manager Approval is a pre-requisite to Stage advancement. So, if Opp Prods need to change, it needs to revert, and go back through approval and advancing the Stage.

Comment: Good day @cropredy, yes, I have, but I do not know how to structure a PRIORVALUE() function to allow for the exception I am looking for.

Comment: please clarify what fields are on OpportunityLineItem and what fields are on Opportunity

Comment: @cropredy, all of the fields mentioned are on the Opportunity with the exception of Product Quantity and Unit Sales Price.